# Wait until a JButton is clicked before ending a method

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am programming a game of tic tac toe that takes turns between a player (a user clicking buttons) and a computer player.

I have a method called `playersTurn()` that needs to wait until a `JButton` is clicked before the method ends and the computer player takes its turn. I have read about using threads and a `wait - notify` method, but I am new to Java and can't figure out how to implement this.

I was wondering if there is a simpler way of overcoming this problem or if this is the only way, and if so could anyone direct me towards a good tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I think you should read about observer desing pattern.

Comment: No, you don't want to use wait - notify here at all. You want to give the game a boolean player0Turn or player1Turn variable, your choice, that you change based on whose turn it is, and then you can base your program's behavior on the state of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

As @HFOE said (+1 to him) you dont want to use `Thread`s with *notify* and *wait* thats really overcomplicating things
The logic for your game is skewed IMO.

Before starting the game lay down some framework:

- 9 `JButton`s (array will hold the buttons)
- `JPanel` with a `GridLayout(3,3)` to create a tic tac toe grid

Now comes the important part:

- Player starts the game and thereafter computer goes and so on

With the above in mind see my example I made the basics is inside the `ActionListener` used for each button after the player has gone (button has been clicked and player symbol set), we call the method for the *cpu* to *play*:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class Test {
    //declare variables for player and cpu symbol

    private String playerSymbol = "X";
    private String cpuSymbol = "O";
    //used for cpu to select random block
    private Random r = new Random();
    //create arraylist to hold buttons
    ArrayList<JButton> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
    //this is the action listner that will be added to each block and will allow player the first turn then cpu goes
    private ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            //players turn
            playerTurn(ae);

            //check for win after player gone
            checkForWin();

            //cpu turn
            cpuTurn();

            //check for a win after cpu goes
            checkForWin();
        }

        private void cpuTurn() {
            System.out.println("CPU goes");
            while (true) {
                int blockNumber = r.nextInt(9);

                System.out.println(blockNumber + "");
                String tmp = blocks.get(blockNumber).getText();

                if (tmp.equals("")) {
                    blocks.get(blockNumber).setText(cpuSymbol);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void checkForWin() {
            System.out.println("Checking for a win...");
        }

        private void playerTurn(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println("Player goes");
            JButton block = (JButton) ae.getSource();
            block.setText(playerSymbol);
        }
    };

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));//create gridlayput to hold buttons

        //create blocks/Jbuttons to hold X and Y
        createBlocks(blocks);
        //add buttons/blocks to the board
        fillBoard(blocks, board);
        //add board to JFrame content pane
        frame.add(board);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void fillBoard(ArrayList<JButton> blocks, JPanel board) {
        for (JButton block : blocks) {
            board.add(block);
        }
    }

    private void createBlocks(ArrayList<JButton> blocks) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            //create new button with a size of 50,50
            JButton block = new JButton() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(50, 50);
                }
            };
            block.addActionListener(al);//add the actionlistner to the button
            blocks.add(block);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //set L&F and create UI on EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {//set L&F
                    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
                }

                //create UI
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U should not wait and test that something happen,
The proper way is to set Listener to Butoon and for example change active player after button click.
But everything depends on your code implemantation.